# How to force the browser to display the physical location sharing acceptance menu

Tags: javascript, geolocation

We are developing an application for tablets, that will be used by some agents. With the help of `geolocation`, everytime an agent opens or closes a task we will save the coordinates.

The thing is, we get the status, whether one accepted or not to share the location. 
So we don't let him go further until he accepts to share the location.

But if he pressed the `'Never for this site'` or something similar, how can we bring back those options so he can say `'Allow'`?

I know they can train all the agents to allow, but "mistakes" can happen :)

Comment: The option “never for this site” is to let the user decide he _does not want_ to be bothered by the site asking him at all/any more. If you could “overwrite” that from within your script … than that option would be pointless. So if your users make that decision, even if by accident only, it’s up to them to change that setting back.

Comment: ok, was hoping there would be a way to work this around...thanks

Comment: I see in website http://whatismyipaddress.com an iframe allowing you to share location, within the contents of the website